# Swift:JSONSerialization SIGABRT error

Tags: swift, xcode, sigabrt, nsjsonserialization

I get SIGABR error for JSONSerialization...here is the code(XCode8)

```
func makeHTTPPostRequest(path: String, body: String, onCompletion: @escaping ServiceResponse) {
    var err: NSError?
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: path)! as URL)

    // Set the method to POST
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // Set the POST body for the request

    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!)
        onCompletion(json, err)
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Here is the value for body variable: {"firstName":"adds","email":"asd","lastName":"add","password":"asdas"}

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to update syntax to swift 3.0

```
let dataTsked = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: path)!) { (data, response, error) in
    if (error != nil) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`body` is not a `JSONObject` but a type of `String`. The function you are trying to use needs a top-level Foundation object like `Dictionary` or `Array`.

You just need to pass body data to the request.

So instead of:

```
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
```

it should be:

```
request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)!
```

Note: body needs to be a well formatted JSON String